# Taking into account the uncertainty of p when estimating the mean of a binomial distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution, credible-interval

I have a binomial distribution with parameters $N$ and $p$, and the estimate for the mean of my distribution is N$\times p$. The values of $N$ and $p$ are such that we can use the Gaussian approximation to estimate the $\sigma$ of the mean as $\sqrt{(n\times p (1-p)}$. The problem is that I have already estimated $p$, so $p$ is actually a Gaussian distribution with a know mean and $\sigma$. My goal is to find a confidence interval for the mean of my binomial distribution, but how do I take the uncertainty of $p$ into account?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach. First, you want to use confidence intervals for something that they were *not* designed for. If $p$ varies, then confidence interval *will not* show you how does it vary. Check [Why does a 95% Confidence Interval (CI) not imply a 95% chance of containing the mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-confidence-interval-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the) to learn more about confidence intervals. Moreover, using normal approximation for binomial proportion and it's confidence intervals is not a good idea, as described by [Brown *et al* (2001)](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~lbrown/Papers/2001a%20Interval%20estimation%20for%20a%20binomial%20proportion%20(with%20T.%20T.%20Cai%20and%20A.%20DasGupta).pdf).

In fact, from your description it sounds like you want to estimate the [Bayesian credible interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval), i.e. interval that will contain certain fraction of $p$'s distribution. Yes, I said *Bayesian*, since in fact you *already* defined your problem as a Bayesian model. You say that you assume that $p$ is a random variable, while in frequentist setting $p$ would be a fixed parameter. If you already assumed it, why not use a Bayesian model for your data? You would be using [beta-binomial model](http://www.obscureanalytics.com/2012/07/04/to-the-basics-bayesian-inference-on-a-binomial-proportion/) (see also [*An introduction to the Beta-Binomial model*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~10701/lecture/technote2_betabinomial.pdf) paper by Dan Navarro and Amy Perfors). In cases like this it is extremely easy to estimate such model. We can define it as follows:

$$
X \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(N, p) \\
p \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)
$$

so, your data $X$ follows binomial distribution parametrized by $N$ and $p$, where $p$ is a random variable. We assume [beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution) with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as a *prior* for $p$. I guess that if you wanted to use frequentist method, you do not have any *prior* knowledge about possible distribution of $p$, so you would choose ["uninformative" *prior*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238089/beta-distribution-on-flipping-a-coin) parametrized by $\alpha = \beta = 1$, or $\alpha = \beta = 0.5$ (if you prefer, you may translate those parameters to [mean and precision](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194182/beta-as-distribution-of-proportions-or-as-continous-binomial), or [mean and variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12232/calculating-the-parameters-of-a-beta-distribution-using-the-mean-and-variance)). After [updating](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237037/bayesian-updating-with-new-data/237109#237109) your *prior*, *posterior* distribution of $p$ is simply a beta distribution parametrized by

$$
\alpha' = \alpha + \text{total number of successes} \\
\beta' = \beta + \text{total number of failures}
$$

with mean

$$ E(X) = N \frac{\alpha'}{\alpha'+\beta'} $$

To read more about calculating other quantities of this distribution check Wikipedia article on [beta-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution). You can compute credible intervals numerically either by (a) inverting numerically the cumulative distribution function of beta-binomial distribution, or by (b) sampling large number of random values from beta-binomial distribution and then computing [sample quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) from it. Second approach is pretty easy since you only need to sequentially repeat the following procedure:

> 1. draw $p$ from beta distribution parametrized by $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$,
> 2. draw $x$ from binomial distribution parametrized by $p$ and $N$.

until you draw sample large enough to find it confident for calculating the quantities of interest.

---

Of course if you know mean and standard deviation of $p$ and you insist on using normal distribution for it, you can use simulation as well, but with using normal distribution for simulating the values of $p$. Below I provide code example in R for such simulation.

```r
R <- 1e5                       # number of samples to draw in simulation
N <- 500                       # known N
mu <- 0.3                      # known mean of p
sigma <- 0.07                  # known standard deviation of p
p <- rnorm(R, mu, sigma)       # simulate p
x <- rbinom(R, N, p)           # simulate X
mean(x)                        # estimate for mean of X
quantile(p*N, c(0.025, 0.975)) # 95% interval estimate for variability of E(X)
```

Or you can simply take appropriate quantiles using inverse of normal cumulative distribution function and multiply them by $N$. Remember however that this is not a confidence interval, but a credible interval.

---

Brown, L.D., Cai, T.T., & DasGupta, A. (2001). [Interval estimation for a binomial proportion.](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~lbrown/Papers/2001a%20Interval%20estimation%20for%20a%20binomial%20proportion%20(with%20T.%20T.%20Cai%20and%20A.%20DasGupta).pdf) Statistical science, 101-117.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I think the second approach is the most useful for me. I don't have any experience with Bayesian statistics, so I need to read some more about that and the beta distribution. I just have one question about step 1 in the second approach: Why would I draw from the beta distribution, and not from the distribution that I know p has?

Comment: @HelgaHolmestad because you would assume p come from beta distribution ;) beta is a much better distribution for p then normal - it is bounded in [0,1], while normal distribution ranges from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Moreover, even if for some reason mean and variance of p are known to you in advance, you can easily find such parameters of beta that correspond to the mean and variance you already know (see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12232/calculating-the-parameters-of-a-beta-distribution-using-the-mean-and-variance ).