# Bernoulli or binomial likelihood, beta prior. Marginalize over success probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

**Background**
Suppose I have observations $y=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ of a binary variable $x_i\in\{0,1\}$ (assumed to be IID).  Observations are generated by some complicated and unknown system $\mathcal F$. To simulate/predict the output of the system I use a function $f(θ)$, parameterized by model parameters $\theta$, leading to model predictions $\hat y_i(\theta)$. My aim is to learn something about the underlying system by interpreting the model parameters $\theta$, i.e. the overall goal is to infer the posterior distribution over $\theta$.

**Likelihood function**
I have considered two different likelihood functions to represent the observations:

*Representation 1* - Bernoulli distributions. Represent observations by modeling the *sequence of observations* by
$$\begin{eqnarray}\displaystyle p(y|\gamma,\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n\gamma^{I(y_i=\hat y_i(\theta))}(1-\gamma)^{I(y_i\neq\hat y_i(\theta))} = \gamma^{s(\theta)}(1-\gamma)^{n-s(\theta)}\end{eqnarray},  \qquad (1)$$
with $\gamma$ being the probability of succes, i.e. correspondence between model prediction and observation, $I()$ being the indicatior function that returns 1 if argument is true and 0 otherwise, and $\displaystyle s=\sum_i I(y_i=\hat y_i(\theta))$.

*Representation 2* - Binomial distribution. Represent data by modeling the *number of successes*
$$\begin{eqnarray}\displaystyle p(y|\gamma,\theta)=\frac{n!}{s(\theta)!(n-s(\theta))!}\gamma^{s(\theta)}(1-\gamma)^{n-s(\theta)}\end{eqnarray}.  \qquad (2)$$

**Prior**
Beta prior
$$\begin{eqnarray}p(\gamma|\alpha,\beta)=\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\gamma^{\alpha - 1}(1-\gamma)^{\beta - 1}\end{eqnarray} $$

**Marginalize over "success probability"**
I am primarily interested in inferences regarding the parameter vector $\theta$ and not $\gamma$. Therefore I marginalize over the success probability $\gamma$
$$\begin{eqnarray}p(y|\theta)=\int_0^1p(y|\gamma,\theta)p(\gamma|\alpha,\beta) d\gamma\end{eqnarray},$$
where I assume $\gamma$ and $\theta$ being independent.

Using *"likelihood representation 1"* above I get
$$\begin{eqnarray} \displaystyle p(y|\theta)&=&
\int_0^1 \gamma^{s(\theta)}(1-\gamma)^{n-s(\theta)}\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\gamma^{\alpha - 1}(1-\gamma)^{\beta - 1} d\gamma \\
&=&\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\int_0^1 \gamma^{s(\theta)+\alpha-1}(1-\gamma)^{n-s(\theta)+\beta-1} d\gamma \\
&=&
\frac{B(s(\theta)+\alpha,n-s(\theta)+\beta)}{B(\alpha,\beta)}.\qquad (3)
\end{eqnarray}  $$

Using *"likelihood representation 2"* above I get
$$\begin{eqnarray} \displaystyle p(y|\theta)&=&
\int_0^1 \frac{n!}{s(\theta)!(n-s(\theta))!}\gamma^{s(\theta)}(1-\gamma)^{n-s(\theta)}\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\gamma^{\alpha - 1}(1-\gamma)^{\beta - 1} d\gamma \\
&=&\frac{n!}{s(\theta)!(n-s(\theta))!B(\alpha,\beta)}\int_0^1 \gamma^{s(\theta)+\alpha-1}(1-\gamma)^{n-s(\theta)+\beta-1} d\gamma \\
&=&
\frac{n!B(s(\theta)+\alpha,n-s(\theta)+\beta)}{s(\theta)!(n-s(\theta))!B(\alpha,\beta)}.\qquad (4)  
\end{eqnarray}  $$
Below, I plot eq. (3) in (A) and eq. (4) in (B) and their logarithms in (C) and (D), respectively, for an example with $n=10$ observations
 [image]

The two likelihood representations in eq. (1-2) lead to quite different behavior in $p(y|\theta)$. For example, using a uniform prior ($\alpha =1, \beta = 1$), $p(y|\theta)$ is uniform (plot (B,D)) when using *likelihood representation 2* eq. (2) , whereas *likelihood representation 1* eq. (1) concentrates most of the probability mass of $p(y|\theta)$ near low and high values of $s(\theta)$ (plot (A,C)).

If I trust my model and believe that it should perform better than chance, I can incorporate this assumption into the probabilistic model by changing the hyperparameters governing the prior over $\gamma$. Fixing $\beta=1$ and letting $\alpha>1$ we see, that *likelihood representation 2* eq. (2) results in $p(y|\theta)$ being monotonically increasing as a function of successes $s(\theta)$ plot (B,D). When using *likelihood representation 1* eq. (1) this also biases the probability mass towards large values of $s(\theta)$, however, $\alpha\geq n+\beta$ before $p(y|\theta)$ is increasing monotonically as a function of successes $s(\theta)$.

**Questions**
1) Theoretical: From a theoretical point of view, are there any reasons for preferring either *likelihood representation 1* eq. (1) or *likelihood representation 2* eq. (2)?

2) Practical: The above probabilistic model is part of a larger probabilistic setup, where I also model the prior governing $\theta$ as well as model other types of observations. For inferences over $\theta$ I use MCMC. Using such an iterative procedure, one concern with using *likelihood representation 1* eq. (1) could be, that the sampling procedure get trapped in regions with low $s(\theta)$ because of non-monotonic behavior of $p(y|\theta)$ if $\alpha<n+\beta$ (imagine $p(y|\theta)$ being sharply peaked at low and high success probabilities). Of course I could assign a high value to $\alpha$, but this, in turn, condenses much of the probability mass near maximal values of $s(\theta)$ relative to the case when using *likelihood representation 2* (compare A  vs. B). Would this concern vote in favor of using *likelihood representation 2*?

Comment: Are you familiar with [beta-binomial model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238571/taking-into-account-the-uncertainty-of-p-when-estimating-the-mean-of-a-binomial/238582#238582) it gives closed-form solution to this problem, MCMC is not needed in here.

Comment: @Tim, many thanks for your comment. I see that eq. (4) above is equal to the beta-binomial model. However, my goal is not to infer the posterior distribution over the success probability parameter but rather to infer the posterior distribution over the parameter vector $\theta$ governing my prediction function $f$. I do not have a fixed number of successes. Rather the number of successes depends on predictions of the model $f$,  which in turn depends (non-linearly) on the parameter vector $\theta$. I also have a prior over the model parameter $\theta$. This is why I use MCMC.

Comment: Then I do not understand your description. Are you dealing with i.i.d. r.v.'s? If not (e.g. $\theta$'s differ) then representation as binomial is incorrect. If number of trials is unknown, then using binomial may be inappropriate (maybe you should use negative-binomial etc.).

Comment: @Tim, but $\theta$ are parameters of the prediction function $f$ and $\gamma$ is the parameter of the Bernoulli / Binomial likelihoods. Does this make sense? Please let me know if I should clarify in the Background description.

Comment: Then what are $f$ and $s$? If I understand you correctly then what you observe is some data generated by $f$. If you are not interested at all in estimating parameters of binomial distribution, then what is the purpose of introducing such model? How would estimating $\gamma$ help in estimating $\theta$?

Comment: @Tim, observations are generated by some complicated and unknown system $\mathcal F$, and $f(\theta)$ is a function that I use to predict/simulating the output of the system. s is the number of observations for which we have correspondence between model prediction and observation. I introduce the models eq. (1) or (2) in order to compare the predictions of the simulation model $f(\theta)$ with the observations. Hence, the purpose is to use  eq. (1) or (2) as a measure that guide us towards model parameters $\theta$ that give good correspondence between model predictions and observations.

Comment: An analogy for continuous y's could be a regression model, parameterized by parameter vector $\theta$, where we are interested in $p(\theta|y)$ and model the likelihood by a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu(\theta)$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and then impose some prior over $\sigma^2$ (and also a prior over $\theta$).

Comment: But then, from what you're saying, it seems that distribution of your data is *fully determined* by $\gamma$ and so $\theta$ must be a deterministic function of $\gamma$, so by learning about $\gamma$ you learn about $\theta$ and it's distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Binomial distribution is a [distribution of sum of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838107/relationship-between-binomial-and-bernoulli) and their [likelihoods are equivalent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144121/logistic-regression-bernoulli-vs-binomial-response-variables/144174#144174). If you are getting different results under both *representations* of your data, then you are doing something wrong.

Moreover, unless I misunderstand your problem, you are making things overcomplicated. Beta distribution is a [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) for $\theta$ parameter of binomial distributions, what leads to [beta-binomial model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238571/taking-into-account-the-uncertainty-of-p-when-estimating-the-mean-of-a-binomial/238582#238582). Under beta-binomial model, posterior predictive distribution of your data follows a [beta-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) parametrized by known number of trials $n$ and parameters

$$
\alpha' = \alpha + \text{total number of successes} \\
\beta' = \beta + \text{total number of failures}
$$

where $\alpha,\beta$ are parameters of beta prior. Marginally $\theta$ is distributed as beta with parameters $\alpha',\beta'$. MCMC is not needed in here since the posterior distribution is directly available in closed-form since conjugacy.

Comment: Thank your for providing this answer. However, I get different results under both representations of the data, because I considered the number of successes to be a function of the parameter vector $\theta$ governing the simulation model $f(\theta)$ rather that a fixed number of observed successes: Hence the representation in eq (4) is equivalent to eq (3) scaled by the factor $n!/(s(\theta)!(n-s(\theta)!))$. (Note that $\theta$ is the parameter governing the simulation model, refer to comments above.)

Comment: @PMR but those two models are equivalent so if you're getting dissent results then you're doing something wrong as noted in the comments and in my answer.